# OneSignal library iOS - linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: swift, notifications, onesignal

i'm trying to import OneSignal library into my Swift project. I use official guide: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ios-sdk-setup

I keep getting this error:

```
linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zORIa.png)

Thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means you're missing OneSignal.h from your bridging header or the bridging header isn't configured correctly in your Xcode project. Double check the steps in [3B. Swift](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ios-sdk-setup#section-3-add-required-code).

Comment: Thank you, the problem was I added framework file into Embedded binaries.

Comment: I am having the same problem. How did you solve it? Thanks @TParizek